# Android TextView fade in animation not working

Tags: android, animation, textview

Here is what in the animation xml :

```
android:fromAlpha="0.0"
android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="4500"
```

and here where I call it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    setContentView(R.layout.prayerlayout);

    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
    txt.setText(getString(R.string.eighth));

//apply animation 
     fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade10);
     txt.startAnimation(fade1);
 }
```

The issue is that the text doesn't show up for the duration of the animation, then it appears suddenly. I didn't notice this problem in older versions of android. It was working fine, but with Lollipop or Jellybeans it doesn't work. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my text was too long causing the fade-in animation not to work. I applied the animation on the scrollView instead, and it did the effect I wanted.

Comment: Could you please give more info about the text length causing the animation not to work? Why is this the case?

Comment: Approximately around 700 words that are above 5000 characters. I have no idea why probably device's processing power or android os software can't handle large text animations. I didn't test it on recent android releases so may be they fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in the fadein XML.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

And the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Animation animFadein,animFadeout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);
        animFadeout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_out);
        Update();
    } 

    public void Update(){
        TextView lblEstadoPuerta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblEstadoPuerta);
        ImageButton btnabrirpuerta = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btndoorstate);

        btnabrirpuerta.startAnimation(animFadeout);
        btnabrirpuerta.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnabrirpuerta.setImageResource(R.drawable.go_down);
        btnabrirpuerta.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnabrirpuerta.startAnimation(animFadein);
    }
}
```

Need to import this..

```
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i'm surprised how this works to some people and does't for others, I have basically same your code but the textview doesn't animate but only comes up suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add some Interpolator?
You can read this:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Your fade10.xml animation file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
    android:duration="4500"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

Your Activity file

```
public class FadeActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txt;
    private Animation fade1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.prayerlayout);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txt.setText(getString(R.string.eighth));

        //apply animation
        fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade10);
        txt.startAnimation(fade1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the interpolator thing, I added it and tried other interpolators and still had no effect. The textview shows up suddenly without animation.